# Develop a decision based game on Amazon alexa

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

I had an idea tonight. Its about developing a game on Alexa where she is telling you a Story and you are the Player who is able to direct the Story in any way he wants to with the decisions he can make.

So an example would be:

[Some Story] .. where do you want to Go:
Pub for 50$
Hotel for 100$
Stay outside for freue

And the User can now decide where He wants to stay and then the Story continous and for example if you stay Out you get robbed and if you Go to the Pub you wake up with headache the next day.

So my question is how am I able to realise this in a smart way so the decisions can affect the Story Line.

My First thought was to Store the complete Story in a 2d String Array to Jump around different Stories but if this becomes a bigger there must be another way.

And I need to be able to Store the Point where I Stopped. Yet I have no idea of how to die this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the story and the user's progress in a database, either by writing an Alexa skill which sends requests to an Amazon Lambda function you would write or a custom web service you would write. Check out [this documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/overviews/steps-to-build-a-custom-skill) for how to get started writing Alexa skills.